# Big theta of a rational function?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

[image]

Im practicing some problems and I'm confused how they went from the function A(n) to that big theta? Did they simplify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2+3n` is `Theta(n)`.

`1+4ln(n)` is `Theta(ln(n))`. So, `5sqrt(n)(1+4ln(n))` is `Theta(sqrt(n)ln(n))`.

Putting this together the fraction is `Theta(n/(sqrt(n)ln(n))) = Theta(sqrt(n)/ln(n))` since `n/sqrt(n) = sqrt(n)`.